# VB.NET MS-WORD Number List with Character Indents

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

So it has been a long time since I have attempted to do any word automation but long story short, I need to create a work document that includes a list. The first level being numbers and the second being letters, basically mimicking the out of the box default numbering format but can't quite get it figured out.

The code I have so far just continues the numeric pattern on indent.

Here is the code I have so far and a screen capture of what I need. Thanks

```
Public NotInheritable Class Utilities
Public Shared Sub CreateDocument()
    'Local Variable Declaration
    Dim application As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim document As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range

    application.Visible = True

    'Add a new document
    document = application.Documents.Add()

    'Add Header and Footer
    For Each Item As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section In document.Sections
        'Header
        Dim header As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range = Item.Headers(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        header.Fields.Add(header, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage)
        header.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
        header.Text = "Header"
        header.Font.Name = "Arial"
        header.Font.Size = 10.0
        header.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorRed

        'Footer
        Dim footer As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range = Item.Footers(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        footer.Fields.Add(footer, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage)
        footer.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
        footer.Text = "Footer"
        footer.Font.Name = "Arial"
        footer.Font.Size = 10.0
        footer.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorRed
    Next

    'Setup Default Range
    range = document.Range()
    range.Style = document.Styles("No Spacing")
    range.Font.Name = "Arial"
    range.Font.Size = 10.0
    range.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorBlack

    range.Text = "Line 1" & vbCrLf
    range.Text &= "Line 2" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    Dim paragraph As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add
    paragraph.Range.Text = "First Numbered Line:"
    paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyNumberDefault(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior)
    paragraph.Outdent()

    Dim list = paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(1).NumberStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter

    paragraph.Range.Paragraphs.Add()
    paragraph.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Second Character Line"
    paragraph.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(document.ListTemplates(1), True, list)
    paragraph.Range.Paragraphs(1).Indent()

    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
End Sub
```

End Class

What I need:
[image]

Comment: easier to Record Macro in Word and check the generated code (that's what I would do to give you the answer anyway). It's one of the list properties, but can't remember it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a couple more hours of messing with this I found the solution.

```
Private Shared Sub SetupParagraphsTemplates(Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)
    ParagraphTemplate = Application.ListGalleries(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(2)
    ParagraphTemplate.ListLevels(1).NumberStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic
    ParagraphTemplate.ListLevels(2).NumberFormat = "%2."
    ParagraphTemplate.ListLevels(2).NumberStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
    ParagraphTemplate.ListLevels(3).NumberStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic
    ParagraphTemplate.ListLevels(3).NumberFormat = "%3."
End Sub
```

Main Method Apply the template:

```
paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(ParagraphTemplate)
```

Then we adding text levels you would use a call like this:

```
‘Text
    range.Paragraphs.Add()
    range.Paragraphs(range.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text = "Test"
    range.Paragraphs(range.Paragraphs.Count).Range.SetListLevel(2)
```

Hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: Hi Josh.
This has helped me with my work on adding a custom numbering list to my word document and then linking in to Styles. I couldn't get the ListGalleries property correctly coded and started up but your code above showed me the way.